# How can i check for existence of color in my linux box?

Tags: linux, shell-script, colors

I want to do something like this in my linux box:

```
if [[ colors exist ]];then
echo "some text in colors"
fi
```

my doubt is :

i am using sed to put colors in log file for some text but if the linux box does not have colors enabled will it modify the log file in unneccsasy way like putting some unnecessary characters like [033m etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps with tput, check available colors count,

```
ncolors=$(tput colors)

if [[ $ncolors -ge 8 ]];then
   # colors available
fi
```

Comment: Since `tput` only checks the $TERM variable, it'll fail to detect if using the program in a pipeline. Standard practice tends to be to check if `stdout` is a TTY as well: `tty(1)` is your friend. Something like `if tty >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && [[ $(tput colors) -ge 8 ]]; then ...` would work well.

Comment: `if [[ $ncolors -gt 2 && $ncolors -lt 8 ]]; then what?; fi`

Answer (score 1):

The tty colors are a characteristic of the *terminal* on which the text is shown. Almost all terminals today handle the ANSI escape sequence, so you can get away with colorizing the text when generated, but you should really do it when it is written (perhaps under the control of the user at the writing end). E.g. set up custom coloring for your text for your pager).

Answer (score 0):

A possible method of detecting whether you are running directly from a terminal emulator, or if the output is being written to a log file instead, is to use `readlink`:

```
if [[ $(readlink -f /dev/stdout) =~ '^/dev/pts/' ]]; then
   # colors available
fi
```

This should normally work on modern linux with udev and procfs. I'm not sure if something more portable exists. This uses the special bash regular expression operator `=~`, so it will only work with bash.

An alternative is, as somebody else already explained, to use `tty >/dev/null`; in your case though, you may only be interested in standard output and not standard input, so you'll want to make your standard output the standard input of `tty`:

```
if tty <&1 >/dev/null; then
   # colors available
fi
```

This would disable colors when you run `./myscript.sh >>log_file`, but enable them when you run `./myscript.sh`.

I'd recommend using `[[ $(tput colors) -ge 8 ]]` as well, so that when the environment variable `TERM` is set to `dumb`, colors won't be output.

If you do write a log file with colors in it, you can still read it; you'll have to use something like `less -r` or `multitail -cT ansi` from a terminal emulator with color support though.